# Display 3 lists as a matrix in C# and MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I have these 3 classes:

```
 public class Product 
     {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public int ClassId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
        }



public class Partner
    {
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }     
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    }



public class Price
    {
        public int PriceId { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public float Cost { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have 3 lists of data:

```
List<Product> products; List<Partner> partners; List<Price> prices;
```

How can I show partners in top row, products in left column and price (if it is available for each partner and product) in cells of table in MVC View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always I would start by designing a view model that will reflect the requirements of the view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PartnerPricesViewModel> PartnerProductPrices { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerPricesViewModel
{
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

and then I will populate this view model in the controller action from our domain models and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Product> products = ...
    List<Partner> partners = ...
    List<Price> prices = ...

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Products = products,
        PartnerProductPrices =
            from partner in partners
            select new PartnerPricesViewModel
            {
                PartnerName = partner.Name,
                Prices = 
                    from product in products
                    select prices.FirstOrDefault(price => 
                        price.PartnerId == partner.PartnerId && 
                        price.ProductId == product.ProductId
                    )
            }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally I will have a corresponding strongly typed view to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
            {
                <th>@product.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var partner in Model.PartnerProductPrices)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@partner.PartnerName</td>
                @foreach (var price in partner.Prices)
                {
                    <td>
                        @if (price != null)
                        {
                            @price.Cost.ToString("c")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // There was no price found matching this 
                            // product and partner => we display an empty cell
                            @:&nbsp;    
                        }
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `prices` list is very SQL friendly, but doesn't really fit the actual problem. I think your prices should be stored in a `Dictionary<Tuple<Product, Partner>, Price>` instead of a `List<Price>`.

Since this is MVC, I would use that dictionary as part of the view-model (along with the products and partners). Then displaying it as a table is going to be very straightforward.